# Linq expression for ILIst works in VB.Net but not C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I was converting some code and using Telerik's Code Converter and then ad hoc changing but came across something that stumped me a little bit.  I want to keep it as close as possible to what it was but am curious best way.  It appears

If I want a generic IList, to use for making Lists in a Dependent Property in WPF that could become and IList of any object.  I can mock it up in a console app like this:

WORKS:

```
Private _listTest As IList

Public Property ListTest As IList
  Get
    Return _listTest
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As IList)
    _listTest = value
  End Set
End Property

Sub Main()
  ListTest = New List(Of Integer)({1, 2, 3, 4})
  Dim items = From p In ListTest
End Sub
```

DOES NOT WORK:

```
private static IList _listTest;

public static IList ListTest
{
  get { return _listTest; }
  set { _listTest = value; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  ListTest = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  //Error:Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'IList'.  'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'p'.
  var items = from p in ListTest;
}
```

The problem with the listing saying the equivalent of being explicit, is this will be done for a generic.  I suppose I could do a listing of object.  But is there a language solution in C# to make it work?

Comment: Vb.net allows for a conversion like that with Option Strict Off. There is no c# equivalent and you will have to change your property/field to be `IList<int>` or add `Cast<int>` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closer C# LINQ query syntax is to specify explicitly `object` as type of the range variable `p`. Also I don't know about VB.NET, but in C# `select` is required (can be skipped only if the last operator is `group by` w/o `into` clause):

```
var items = from object p in ListTest select p;
```

**Reference:** [How to: Query an ArrayList with LINQ (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693091.aspx) vs [How to: Query an ArrayList with LINQ (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt692817.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should either consider to make your list of generic type `IList<object>` or every time you try to use Linq methods  with your list you should use `.OfType<T>` or `.Cast<T>`.

```
var items = from p in ListTest.Cast<object>() select p;
```

Comment: This won't compile.